# Check user if activated before logging in

Tags: wordpress

How to make the WordPress to check the usermeta value before logging in?

I want to check if user is activated, if not activated then redirect him to other page.
I know how to read usermeta value from database, i can check if it is true or false, but where do i need to insert my code in WordPress or how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, paste this code in your theme's `functions.php`

```
function check_login($user, $username, $password) {
    if(empty($username)) {  
        // wp_redirect(...);
        exit;
    }
    $user = get_userdatabylogin($username); 
    // now check if user is allowed
    if( /* if not allowed */ ) {
        // wp_redirect(...);
        exit;
    }
    return $user;
}
add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login', 99, 3);
```